# Upload base64 string image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, base64

I have a plugin which crops my image and sends back a base64 data that looks like this: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ...`. How can I upload this returned image via file upload field in my form to my server?

[image]

PS: In short I want to automaticly add returned image to my file input field of my form.

Comment: Refer this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlxsGdIJ6x8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you upload any other string to your server.
The fact that the string is Base64 doesn't change anything.

You can put it in an `<input type="hidden">`, then use PHP code to decode the Base64 and save the bytes somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$image =chunk_split( base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image_name']['tmp_name'])));
```